# Complex Regular Expression, PEG, or Multiple Passes?

Tags: regex, parsing, string-parsing

I am trying to extract some data from the following examples:

- Name 789, 10-mill 12-27b
- Manufacturer XY-2822, 10-mill, 17-25b
- Other Manufacturer 16b Part
- Another Manufacturer FER M9000, 11-mill, 11-40
- 18b Part
- Maker 11-31, 10-mill
- Maker 1x or 2x; max size 1x (34b), 2x (38/24b)
- Maker REC6 15/18/26b. Square.
- Producer FC-40 11-13-16-19-22-25-27-30-34b

What I'd like my results to be respectively are:

- 12, 27
- 17, 25
- 16
- 11, 40
- 18
- 11-31
- 34, 38, 24 (optional, its fine if only the latter two are provided)
- 15, 18, 26
- 11, 13, 16, 19, 22, 25, 27, 30, 34

I am happy to do this in multiple passes, using an expression grammar though I don't think that'll really help.

I'm having trouble using lookaheads and lookbehinds to grab that data and exclude things like "11-mill" and "XY-2822". What I find happening is I am able to exclude those matches but end up truncating good results for others matches.

What is the best way to go about this?

My current regex is 
`/(?:(\d+)[b\b\/-])([b\d\b]*)[^a-z]/i`

which is capturing the letter 'b' (which is okay) but not capturing 34b in the final example

Comment: What is the regex flavor? Post the code you have. I can only suggest a PCRE/Oniguruma regex with `\G`.

Comment: @stribizhev I'm using Ruby, give me a moment on posting what I have, I closed my browser tabs after I gave up, I have to get back to where I was on rubular

Comment: @stribizhev edited with my current regex

Comment: You may try [this one](http://ideone.com/BgBqLE). Actually, you would just need to get rid of empty matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what are your exact requirements/formats but you can try this:

```
/(?:\G(?!^)[-\/]|^(?:.*[^\d\/-])?)\K\d++(?![-\/]\D)/
```

http://rubular.com/r/WJqcCNe2pr

details:

```
# two possible starts:
(?: # next occurrences
    \G    # anchor for the position after the previous match
    (?!^) # not at the start of the line
    [-\/]
  | # first occurrence
    ^
    (?:.*[^\d\/-])? # (note the greedy quantifier here,
                    #  to obtain the last result of the line)
)

\K # discards characters matched before from the whole match
\d++ # several digits with a possessive quantifier to forbid backtracking
(?![-\/]\D) # not followed by an hyphen of a slash and a non-digit
```

You can improve the pattern if you replace `(?:.*[^\d\/-])?` with `[^-\d\/\n]*+(?>[-\d\/]+[^-\d\/\n]+)*` *(remove the `\n` if you work line by line.)*. The goal of this change is to limit the backtracking (that occurs atomic group by atomic group, instead of character by character for the first version).

Perhaps, you can replace the negative lookahead with this kind of positive lookahead: `(?=[-\/]\d|b|$)`

An other version [here](https://regex101.com/r/iD8jR2/1).

Comment: Yes, I am working line by line, these are all individual cases. Your answer is good, but on rubular it doesn't seem to match a couple of the examples. #4 and the second to last

Comment: @whistler: all examples seems to works (follow the link)

Comment: Indeed it does, I think rubular is a bit slow atm, wasn't refreshing the matches. This is incredible work.

Comment: @whistler: I added a line break in the negated character class (but it's only to emulate a line by line work, with a multiline text for rubular, in your code, you don't need to add it).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this:

```
(?<=\d-)\d+|\d+(?=-\d+)|\d+(?=(?:\/\d+)*b)
```

https://regex101.com/r/nR3eS9/1

Comment: Incredible, okay, can you explain it a bit more to me though?

What I'm reading is: three regexes by virtue of the pipe. The first has a positive lookbehind which asserts the existence of a digit and a dash in order to match one or more digits

The second matches one or more digits and then has a lookahead which asserts a dash and a run of one more digits.

The third matches one or more digits and again has a positive lookahead which matches (but doesn't capture) on forward slashes and one or more digits, this whole portion can occur any number of times and must be followed by the letter b.

Comment: Yep that's exactly it.